# What to do after asking silly question?

Tags: discussion, questions

What should one do when they feel they have asked a silly question and it may not help other Stack Exchange users?

Comment: What do you mean by "silly?"

Comment: @Robert Hervey Sir, I mean - something for which not able to make right perception of a very simple logic / information

Comment: Ah, well users who speak and write English as a second language can have a hard time here.  We do the best we can to accomodate them, but sometimes it's difficult.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't worry. There are other genuine users and moderators who take care of it by **editing** the question or **closing** the question (for e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11218731)). However, you can:

1. edit your question.
2. delete your question if it hasn't been answered.
3. close your question by flagging for moderator attention (if you don't have the privilege to vote-to-close your own questions yet).